# Combine multiple queries against one table into multiple fields of one result set

Tags: mysql, sql, field, multiple-records

**ANSWER**: Here's the final query built from @Michael 's answer:

```
SELECT 
    Emp_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Skill_ID = 'WLN' THEN (Rating > 0) END) AS `WLN`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Skill_ID = 'LOC' THEN (Rating > 0) END) AS `LOC`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Skill_ID = 'BRV' THEN (Rating > 0) END) AS `BRV`,
    AVG(CASE WHEN Skill_ID IN ('KWH','SIC','DOL') THEN (Rating) END) > 0 AS `KSD`
FROM Emp_Skill
WHERE Emp_ID IN (120,348,361,370)
GROUP BY Emp_ID
```

---

**QUESTION**:

I have the following `Emp_Skill` table:

```
Skill_ID*  Emp_ID*  Rating
--------------------------
     WLN      120        6
     WLN      348        5
     WLN      361        7
     WLN      370        8
     LOC      120        7
     LOC      370        7
     LOC      348        7
     BRV      120        3
     LOC      361        6
     BRV      348        1
     KWH      348        5
     KWH      120        5
     KWH      361        5
     KWH      370        5
     SIC      361        8
     SIC      348        4
     SIC      120        2
     DOL      348        5
     DOL      361        8
```

and I need to know **if an arbitrary number of employees have a positive skill rating for each skill**.

So let's say I want to look at this info for employees *120*, *348*, *361* and *370*.

*Query 1* for skill `WLN` is:

```
SELECT `Emp_ID`, `Rating` > 0 AS `WLN` FROM `Emp_Skill` WHERE `Skill_ID` = 'WLN' AND `Emp_ID` IN (120,348,361,370)
```

which returns:

```
Emp_ID   WLN
------------
   120     1
   348     1
   361     1
   370     1
```

*Query 2* for skill `LOC` is:

```
SELECT `Emp_ID`, `Rating` > 0 AS `LOC` FROM `Emp_Skill` WHERE `Skill_ID` = 'LOC' AND `Emp_ID` IN (120,348,361,370)
```

which returns:

```
Emp_ID   LOC
------------
   120     1
   348     1
   361     1
   370     1
```

*Query 3* for skill `BRV` is:

```
SELECT `Emp_ID`, `Rating` > 0 AS `BRV` FROM `Emp_Skill` WHERE `Skill_ID` = 'BRV' AND `Emp_ID` IN (120,348,361,370)
```

which returns:

```
Emp_ID   BRV
------------
   120     1
   348     1
```

and *Query 4* for skill `KSD` is:

```
SELECT `Emp_ID`, AVG(`Rating`) > 0 AS `KSD` FROM `Emp_Skill` WHERE `Skill_ID` IN ('KWH','SIC','DOL') AND `Emp_ID` IN (120,348,361,370) GROUP BY `Emp_ID`
```

which returns:

```
Emp_ID   KSD
------------
   120     1
   348     1
   361     1
   370     1
```

*Question* is: **How do I efficiently combine these queries into one result table and have them all in one go**, i.e.:

```
Emp_ID   WLN   LOC   BRV   KSD
------------------------------
   120     1     1     1     1
   348     1     1     1     1
   361     1     1  NULL?    1
   370     1     1  NULL?    1
```

possibly from a combined `SELECT` statement? (the *`NULL`* value could be anything that evaluates to `FALSE` in the returned result set)

**OR**: performance-wise, will it be better if I just query each skill rating one by one (using the 4 queries above)?

Sorry if this is elementary for some peeps out there, but I've pulled a lot of hair out and I still haven't killed this. lol. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done with a pivot query, which amounts to a bunch of `CASE` statements.  I think this should get you close to what you need:

```
SELECT 
  Emp_ID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Skill_ID = 'WLN' THEN  (Rating > 0) END) AS `WLN`,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Skill_ID = 'LOC' THEN  (Rating > 0) END) AS `LOC`,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Skill_ID = 'BRV' THEN  (Rating > 0) END) AS `BRV`,
  AVG(CASE WHEN Skill_ID IN ('KWH','SIC','DOL') THEN  (Rating > 0) END) AS `KSD`
FROM Emp_Skill
GROUP BY Emp_ID
```

Comment: thanks @Michael however, only `'WLN'` is giving me results. the other fields `'LOC'`, `'BRV'` and `'KSD'` are all returning *`NULL`*.. hmmm.. any idea why?

Comment: @AnaBan Try it with each surrounded in an aggregate `MAX()` as I added above.

Comment: sweet! that did it! (mind explaining why?) and one last but really important thing, *Query 4* is an `AVG`, but when i change the 4th case in your answer to `MAX(CASE WHEN Skill_ID IN ('KWH','SIC','DOL') THEN  (AVG(Rating) > 0) END) AS KSD` it blows "#1111 - Invalid use of group function", and when i take the `MAX()` out it goes but the `KSD` column gives *`NULL`* again.. help.. :D

Comment: boo-yeah! i changed it to `AVG(CASE WHEN Skill_ID IN ('KWH','SIC','DOL') THEN (Rating > 0) END) AS KSD` and it worked! did i do the right thing? so i can mark your answer as accepted, man. yer epic.

Comment: @AnaBan The `MAX()` works because the `GROUP BY` effectively grabs the first row for any `Emp_ID` since the other columns weren't included in the group.  By using `MAX()` instead of the first row per group, it picks the highest value per group eliminating the NULLs.  Sorry I didn't notice the difference for the last query.  You're correct to use an `AVG()` aggregate there. I'll edit above too.